# Why .jpeg file save via writetofile using UIImageJPEGRepresentation method have large size then UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimagejpegrepresentation

I am trying to save an `UIImage` object to an .jpeg file in device
and I am using this code:

```
-(void)saveImageToDocumentsDirectory:(UIImage *)mimage withFileName:(NSString *)fileName 
{
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(mimage,nil,nil,nil);
    NSData *dataForJPEGFile = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(mimage, 1.0);
    NSError *error2 = nil;
    if (![dataForJPEGFile writeToFile:[self getDirectoryFilePath:fileName] options:NSAtomicWrite error:&error2])
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

It will save the image of .jpeg type but take too much memory as compare to the `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(mimage,nil,nil,nil)` method, which saves the same image object in .jpeg type and same quality.

My question is why so..??

Comment: "Same quality" is subjective, have you tried to gradually decrease the image quality parameter until the sizes are about the same and the quality is still "the same" ?

Comment: @A-Live when i decrease the image quality parameter the size also decreases and quality too. but i want to save the image as this  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(mimage,nil,nil,nil) method does. how can i achieve this..??

Comment: Easy, use UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum.

Comment: @A-Live if i use UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum then how can i get these image back for further use without using imagePicker..??

Comment: Using completionSelector parameter ?

Comment: @A-Live thanks a lot for your help. now when I am saving the image using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum in the device and after done some short of other task if user want to upload this image file to the server then I don't find how can i get this file at the time of uploading.. that the real problem now i am facing.

Comment: Depends on your app design, either keep a copy of the UIImage in memory or on disk or ask the user to pick it again. I don't know if there's any kind of a persistent descriptor to get back to the image at the system media storage once it is saved, not likely.

Comment: Was the solution for the issue found out?