# Save last clicked image from gallery to document directory in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimage, uikit

I want to save the last clicked image saved in Photos gallery to document directory. How can i achieve it.?

Comment: I think you mean by memory disk space. Am I right with that assumption? The only explanation that I can think of is that images in the photos library are compressed.

Comment: @ok404 - yes i mean by memory disk space. have you any solution for this..?

Comment: Why duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34740631/why-jpeg-file-save-via-writetofile-using-uiimagejpegrepresentation-method-have ?

Answer (score 0):

In your code change `NSData *dataForJPEGFile = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(mimage, 1.0);` to

NSData *dataForJPEGFile = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(mimage, 0.5);

This code 0.5 means 50% of your image will compress.

```
    - (void)saveImageToDocumentsDirectory:(UIImage *)mimage withFileName:(NSString *)fileName {
                NSData *dataForJPEGFile = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(mimage, 0.5);
                [dataForJPEGFile writeToFile:[self getDirectoryFilePath:fileName] atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: thanx for answering. but I need image with 100% quality not with 50%.

Comment: try `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(mimage, 1.0)`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the saved photo in your PhotosAlbum is correct size and quality. iOS has an issue, see link: [UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum saves to wrong size and quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379274/uiimagewritetosavedphotosalbum-saves-to-wrong-size-and-quality/3314686#3314686)

For some pictures, the PNG format will be smaller than JPG format. You can try to save picture via UIImagePNGRepresentation.